# CD read speed issues on Vista

Tags: compact-disc

I have a disc for a old game (IL-2 Sturmovik: Forgotten Battles) that during installation, took a ridiculously long time to install on my Windows Vista laptop (we're talking the progress bar moving 10% in one hour). While the game was installing, the disc drive was making an alarming amount of noise.

I had a game before that had a similar issue, which was solved by making an ISO of the disc, then installing from that. So I tried with this disc. And then ImgBurn showed the likely cause. The read speed for the drive with that disc showed up as a mere 1.2x. Given that the selection while setting up ImgBurn gave speeds of up to 56x, and the fact that it was painfully slow, I'm presuming this is CD speeds.

Bad disc maybe? So I tried it on a Windows XP desktop I had lying around, installing in around 5 minutes. It worked perfectly. Then I tried it on my brother's laptop, which ran Windows Vista, *and* had the exact same drive as my own one. It also worked perfectly.

So why can't my drive read this disc?

Possibly related:

- Doing anything with this disc causes my drive to stop working until I restart my computer. The buttons on my laptop stop working, and trying to view it in explorer causes it to freeze.
- It's a slim drive.

Comment: You say the drive is the "exact" same model number as your brothers?, but is the firmware on the drive the same?... use Nero InfoTool to see what firmware version is installed  http://www.nero.com/enu/support-nero8-tools-utilities.html

Answer (score -1):

I borrowed an old IL-2 game from my local library and tried to install it on my Windows 7 Acer laptop.

After half an hour I got impatient and cancelled the installation, when the "are you sure you want to cancel?" screen popped up, I noticed the installation progress bar moved from 0 to 32%, so I went on.

After repeating the procedure a few times, the progress bar jumped a couple of percent each time, and I ended up installing the game in about 10 minutes.